# Error in sankey plot variables in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, shinydashboard, sankey-diagram

Please run the script below, there are two charts created using the patients dataset from the bupaR library, the chart on the left displays a sankey chart showing relationship between the resource("employee") and activities("handling") and the chart on the right displays the details of link between the resource and activities when we perform "on-click". Basically, we see a subset of data with corresponding values say "r1" and "Registration" values when we click the link connecting "r1" to "Registration" and so on. However, when I run code with any other resource and activity column, the sankey chart does not get created and I get the following error "non-numeric argument to binary operator". Please try the script with a simple dataset and help:

```
a1 = c("A","B","C","A","B","B")
a2 = c("D","E","D","E","D","F")
a12 = data.frame(a1,a2)   

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(devtools)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(proto)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(gapminder)
library(stringr)
library(broom)
library(mnormt)
library(DT)
library(bupaR)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Sankey Chart"),
dashboardSidebar(
width = 0
),
dashboardBody(
box(title = "Sankey Chart", status = "primary",height = "455" ,solidHeader = 
T,
    plotlyOutput("sankey_plot")),

box( title = "Case Summary", status = "primary", height = "455",solidHeader 
= T, 
     dataTableOutput("sankey_table"))
 )
 )
 server <- function(input, output) 
 { 
 sankeyData <- reactive({
 sankeyData <- patients %>% 
  group_by(employee,handling) %>% 
  count()
  sankeyNodes <- list(label = c(sankeyData$employee,sankeyData$handling))
  trace2 <- list(
  domain = list(
    x = c(0, 1), 
    y = c(0, 1)
   ), 
   link = list(
    label = paste0("Case",1:nrow(sankeyData)), 
    source = sapply(sankeyData$employee,function(e) {which(e == 

    sankeyNodes$label) }, USE.NAMES = FALSE) - 1, 
    target = sapply(sankeyData$handling,function(e) {which(e == 

    sankeyNodes$label) }, USE.NAMES = FALSE) - 1, 
    value = sankeyData$n
    ), 
    node = list(label = sankeyNodes$label), 
     type = "sankey"
     )
     trace2
      })
    output$sankey_plot <- renderPlotly({
    trace2 <- sankeyData()
    p <- plot_ly()
    p <- add_trace(p, domain=trace2$domain, link=trace2$link, 
               node=trace2$node, type=trace2$type)
    p
    })
    output$sankey_table <- renderDataTable({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    req(d)
    trace2 <- sankeyData()
    sIdx <-  trace2$link$source[d$pointNumber+1]
    Source <- trace2$node$label[sIdx + 1 ]
    tIdx <- trace2$link$target[d$pointNumber+1]
    Target <- trace2$node$label[tIdx+1]
    patients %>% filter(employee == Source & handling == Target)
    })
    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: you did not provide patients

Comment: @MLavoie, Thanks for replying, ok, patients is a built in evenlog from the bupaR package. It comes handy once the package is installed, the package bupar appears in the libraries declared.

Comment: my bad....I can't reproduce your error "non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Comment: @MLavoie, I didn't understand, I hope you understood my requirement?

Comment: I don't see "non-numeric argument to binary operator when I run your app

Comment: @MLavoie, the code I have given is a ready solution, what I asked for is to replace the handling and employee column and patients data with some other data and test it. You can use a simple data like the three lines at the top of the script.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make this "ready solution" with any dataset I think you need one character (cut and color were turned into character using `as.character()`) of column b for each character of column a. For example, in the patient dataset, there is only one possibility (registration) for r1; same for r2 to r7. Your app did not work with the full `diamonds` dataset. But using the same logic, the app works.

```
diamonds_b <- diamonds %>% filter(cut == "Ideal" & color == "D")
diamonds_c <- diamonds %>% filter(cut == "Fair" & color == "E")
diamonds_d <- rbind(diamonds_b, diamonds_c)
diamonds_d$cut <- as.character(diamonds_d$cut)
diamonds_d$color <- as.character(diamonds_d$color)
```

and now running the shiny app with the diamonds_d dataset works:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Sankey Chart"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 0
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    box(title = "Sankey Chart", status = "primary",height = "455" ,solidHeader = 
          T,
        plotlyOutput("sankey_plot")),

    box( title = "Case Summary", status = "primary", height = "455",solidHeader 
         = T, 
         dataTableOutput("sankey_table"))
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) 
{ 
  sankeyData <- reactive({
    sankeyData <- diamonds_d %>% 
      group_by(cut,color) %>% 
      count()
    sankeyNodes <- list(label = c(sankeyData$cut,sankeyData$color))
    trace2 <- list(
      domain = list(
        x = c(0, 1), 
        y = c(0, 1)
      ), 
      link = list(
        label = paste0("Case",1:nrow(sankeyData)), 
        source = sapply(sankeyData$cut,function(e) {which(e == sankeyNodes$label) }, USE.NAMES = FALSE) - 1, 
        target = sapply(sankeyData$color,function(e) {which(e == sankeyNodes$label) }, USE.NAMES = FALSE) - 1, 
        value = sankeyData$n
      ), 
      node = list(label = sankeyNodes$label), 
      type = "sankey"
    )
    trace2
  })
  output$sankey_plot <- renderPlotly({
    trace2 <- sankeyData()
    p <- plot_ly()
    p <- add_trace(p, domain=trace2$domain, link=trace2$link, 
                   node=trace2$node, type=trace2$type)
    p
  })
  output$sankey_table <- renderDataTable({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    req(d)
    trace2 <- sankeyData()
    sIdx <-  trace2$link$source[d$pointNumber+1]
    Source <- trace2$node$label[sIdx + 1 ]
    tIdx <- trace2$link$target[d$pointNumber+1]
    Target <- trace2$node$label[tIdx+1]
    diamonds %>% filter(cut == Source & color == Target)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, couple of points here, I am still getting the same error running this, secondly, suppose I have 1000 resources and 1000 activities, with multiple resources linked to multiple activities, do you think this sankey plot can give me such a result.

Comment: I just specified that cut and color were turned into a character. They were originally ordinal. And as for your second question I think you need one resource per activity in order to run this code. It might be possible to have multiple resources linked to multiple activities but maybe this could be another question on SO.

Comment: Hi, See the functionality that you shall provide me, I have to apply this on a complex set of data, that's why I asked using a basic example, it is not necessary that one resource will be linked to only one activity. Kindly suggest.

Comment: I answered your question. This code works with any data set. Next  time use a *reproducible* example and ask a better question